# Snackbar hidden by bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-snackbar

My `Snackbar` is being hidden by the bottom navigation buttons.

[image: Hidden Snackbar]

The `Activity` is able to toggle full screen mode and I do not want to use margins offsets to fix this.

My XML layout is:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/image_background"
    tools:context="link.standen.michael.slideshow.ImageActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"/>

    <!-- Image Details Overlay -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_details1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:padding="@dimen/overlay_padding">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls_buttons"
                style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@color/black_overlay"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                ...
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Image Details Overlay -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_details2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls_buttons"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/black_overlay"
                android:padding="@dimen/overlay_padding">

             ...

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I've tried positioning the snackbar at various elements on the screen as is but it always seems to hide behind the bottom navigation buttons when the application is not in full screen mode.

Flags used for full screen viewing:

```
mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

What changes do I need to make to the layout to get the snackbar aligned correctly?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your layout in a CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: @AviCherry Coordinator layout doesn't seem to make a different.

Comment: What about adding android:fitsSystemWindows=”true” to your layout?

Comment: `android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”` is already in my layout. It's on the nested `FrameLayout`. I've tried added `coordinatorLayout` within this and using it as the source view for the `snackbar` as well, but this causes the `snackbar` to appear in the same place, even when in fullscreen (i.e. not attached to the bottom of the screen).

Comment: When you're going out of full screen mode are you reversing all of those flags?

Comment: You can't "reverse" the flags, some don't have direct opposites. But yes, I am applying the relevant flags back when returning from full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

When the application is in full screen mode, the `snackbar` is attached to the primary full screen content. `R.id.fullscreen_content` in this case.

When the application is not in full screen mode, the `snackbar` is attached to a new `CoorderinatorLayout` that is nested in the `FrameLayout` with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.

Would be nice to not have to manage it like this, but the solution works. Let me know if there is anything better.